# multi-sig transactions, not on contract-level

Tags: signature, multisignature

Is it possible in Ethereum to issue multi-sig transactions which are *not implemented on smart contract level* but instead via signing, similar to Bitcoin?

The following would be an example of a multi-sig transaction - might work in practice differently, just for sake of argument:

```
signature1 = sign(privateKey1, message);
signature2 = sign(privateKey2, signature2);
```

**Background + Motivation**: I am doing a thought experiment whether or not it makes sense to block transactions that have code associated (instead of being private key-controlled). E.g.: If one issued a `centralized-fiat-token` and wants to ensure KYC-compliance, one might want to only allow these `centralized-fiat-token` to be sendable to and from KYC-approved addresses. However, these addresses could actually be controlling a multi-sig wallet or even be a proxy contract that gives other non-KYC-compliant parties access to these tokens. To prevent that, one could limit transferrability to only approved addresses that do not have any associated code.

[This is obviously a bad idea because, 1) e.g. the mist wallet is/was a code-controlled wallet and as such be locked-out, 2) I might want to move funds to another account that I control myself, without undergoing (parts of) the KYC procedure again.]

If we could show that multi-sig transactions are anyway possible even without code in multi-private-key scenarios, then the whole argumentation of blocking code-controlled addresses would break down.

Comment: Have you seen EIP86? https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/86

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intuition is correct and it's easy to make a proof-of-concept, although it has some limitations.

A and B want shared access to funds so they both have to sign to spend them.

A and B each make their own private key. They exchange hashes of their public keys (*), then the actual public keys.

They add their public keys together using ECC addition. You can do this with pybitcointools. This creates a new public key. They make this into an address.

They send money to the address (or do whatever they're trying to do).

To spend the money, A sends their private key to B, who adds to private keys together to make the private key of the public key they made earlier. A spends the money.

(*) I think you can do ECC multiplication instead of addition and avoid this step, but I'd have to check it works the way I think it does.